# Error in Chroma vector database langchain

Tags: python, langchain, openaiembeddings

I am trying to work with Chroma vector database from langchain but when I try to use it I am getting NotFoundError. I have installed required dependencies and set the openai api key.

```
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings 
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
db = Chroma.from_documents (texts, embeddings)
```

I want this to execute successfully.

I am getting below error.

```
NotFoundError: Error code: 404 {'error': {'code': '404', 'message': 'Resource not found'}}
```

Comment: Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre]. We need the full traceback and information about what data you provided (in particular, what is `texts`)?

Answer (score 0):

Giving you an example of code using `chroma` as vectorstore

```py
from langchain_community.document_loaders import WebBaseLoader
loader = WebBaseLoader("https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Hans_Andersen%27s_Fairy_Tales/The_Emperor%27s_New_Clothes")
documents = loader.load()


from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=2000,
                                               chunk_overlap=200)
texts = splitter.split_documents(documents)

from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
db = Chroma.from_documents(texts, embeddings)

print(type(db))
```

Comment: Well, I tried this code and still getting same error, I am using python 3.10 version. Not sure what is the issue

Comment: Can you upgrade LangChain to latest version, `pip install -U langchain langchain-community`